# Write figure caption in one line using \mbox and split figure caption two line in the list of figure

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I want to write figure caption. The figure caption is long and split into two line, where second line is consist of one letter. Now I want to make it one line.

[image]

This is original code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \listoffigures
    \chapter{one}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla A}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To make caption in one line , I use `\mbox` become

`\caption{\mbox{blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla A}}`.

Now, the caption become one line.

[image]

Now, my problem is in the list of figure. In the list of figure also become one line. I want to split caption in two line in list of figure. How to make it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want `\caption[blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla A]{\mbox{blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla A}}`?

Comment: Yes, right. I want it. Thanks.